# SQL WHERE function not returning any results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a very simple query that I want to use to return any results where column 'courses' contains the keyword search.

You can see from the screenshot attached that there are multiple rows that contain 'Sep 2022 - Design' in the courses column but nothing is being  returned.

```
SELECT dealname, email, courses
FROM `airbyte-bigquery.hubspot_airbyte.deals_properties`
WHERE closedate > '2022-09-01'AND courses LIKE "%SEP 2022 - Global Design%"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g8Ek.png)

Comment: Is nothing returned or do you get an error message of some type?

Comment: The query runs but no results are returned. 

There are multiple values entered in the courses column, separated by semi-colons so I'm not sure if that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: Try running the query as WHERE closedate > '2022-09-01'AND courses LIKE "SEP 2022 - Global Design%"

Comment: Leave off the first %

Comment: No dice with that solution!

Comment: use `lower(courses) LIKE "%sep 2022 - global design%"` instead of `courses LIKE "%SEP 2022 - Global Design%"`

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that solution seemed to work. Any idea why? lol

Comment: @YosufHariq: the rows in your screenshot contain "Sep 2022", not "SEP 2022" (which you wrote in your query).

Comment: LIKE is case sensitive :D , so if you don't want to check exact case then either do upper or lower on both sides to make sure you won't get into these kind of surprises.